# Create newline between two ionic form elements

Tags: html, css

How do I force a newline between the following Ionic form elements?

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Code so far:

```
    <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Current Location">
        </label>
    </div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o5z6d8z0/

Comment: You want to display always in new line or when screen size small?

Comment: I'd like to simply display on a new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply add `flex-flow: column` to `.item-input-inset` will down the second label to first.

```
.item-input-inset{
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5z6d8z0/1/)**

Answer (score 5):

Add this css

```
.item-input-wrapper {
   margin-top: 10px;    
 }

.item-input-inset {    
   display: block;   
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o5z6d8z0/5/)**